# How to deal with the ending 5 in a decimal fraction when round it

Tags: python, math

I was using python to round float numbers，and I'm confused by how the computer round numbers. For example：

```
round(1.55, 1) = 1.6 # this is what I would expect; however
round(1.65, 1) = 1.6 #this is what confuses me. Is it supposed to be 1.7?
```

Another example:

```
round(1.85, 1) = 1.9
round(1.95, 1) = 1.9
```

I guess this may have something to do with the conversion between binary and decimal. My question is how do I know whether the ending 5 would be omitted or not? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Python uses [banker's rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even). This is the default rounding mode used in IEEE 754 computing functions and operators.

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)? There's a note on this issue.

Comment: @Cyber if that's true then why don't `round(1.5, 0)` and `round(2.5, 0)` both return `2.0`?

Comment: @MarkRansom Interesting. I'd have to look into it, but I suspect that `1.5` is actually `1.499999999...` so would round down to `1` but I would have to do some investigating.

Comment: Thank you very much, guys. I read the document and learned that you can import decimal module, and then used Decimal(Your number) to check the exact value whenever you are in doubt. This is really helpful.

Comment: @Cyber: Python 2.7 rounds ties away from zero.  Only Python 3.x rounds ties to even.  (Python 2.6 and earlier don't have a correctly-rounded round function, so behaviour of halfway cases is unpredictable.)  1.5 is exactly 1.5.

Comment: @Cyber that's why I tried those particular examples, because the floating point representation of numbers ending in `.5` is exact (until they get really large).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) describes why this behavior occurs:

> **Note** 
>   The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for example,
>   round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This is not a
>   bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be
>   represented exactly as a float. See Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues
>   and Limitations for more information.

Related, but beyond the scope of this question, the [Floating Point Arithmetic limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) is a good read as well.

From that page, the issue is expanded as such:

> The documentation for the built-in round() function says that it
>   rounds to the nearest value, rounding ties away from zero. Since the
>   decimal fraction 2.675 is exactly halfway between 2.67 and 2.68, you
>   might expect the result here to be (a binary approximation to) 2.68.
>   It’s not, because when the decimal string 2.675 is converted to a
>   binary floating-point number, it’s again replaced with a binary
>   approximation, whose exact value is
>
> 2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
>
> Since this approximation is slightly closer to 2.67 than to 2.68, it’s rounded down.